# How to resize a datatable in order to fit it in a box() for shinyDashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I don't know how to make sure the size of my `DT::renderDataTable` fit in my box.

Here is a picture of my Shiny Render

[image]

Does anybody know how to make sure the table fit in the box ? Or can I add a slider under the table to scroll around other variables that are not on the screen ?

Here is my code:

***server.R***

```
output$table = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
      round(df,2), 
      rownames = TRUE,
      extensions = 'Buttons',
      options = list(
        autoWidth = FALSE, 
        columnDefs = list(list(width = "125px", targets = "_all")),
        dom = 'tpB',
        lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All')),
        pageLength = 15,
        buttons = list(
          list(
            extend = "collection",
            text = 'Show More',
            action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                              dt.page.len(50);
                              dt.ajax.reload();}")
          ),list(
            extend = "collection",
            text = 'Show Less',
            action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                              dt.page.len(10);
                              dt.ajax.reload();}")
            
          )
        )
      )
    )
  
  })
```

***body.R***

```
        box( title = "A little taste of the dataset",
             width = 12,
             DT::dataTableOutput("table") )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply add `scrollX = TRUE` to the datatable options:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

DF <- data.frame(replicate(50, runif(1000, 0, 10)))

ui <- fluidPage(box(
  title = "A little taste of the dataset",
  width = 12,
  DT::dataTableOutput("myTable")
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myTable = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
      round(DF, 2),
      rownames = TRUE,
      extensions = 'Buttons',
      options = list(
        autoWidth = FALSE, scrollX = TRUE,
        columnDefs = list(list(
          width = "125px", targets = "_all"
        )),
        dom = 'tpB',
        lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15,-1), c('5', '15', 'All')),
        pageLength = 15,
        buttons = list(
          list(
            extend = "collection",
            text = 'Show More',
            action = DT::JS(
              "function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                              dt.page.len(50);
                              dt.ajax.reload();}"
            )
          ),
          list(
            extend = "collection",
            text = 'Show Less',
            action = DT::JS(
              "function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                              dt.page.len(10);
                              dt.ajax.reload();}"
            )

          )
        )
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```